# How to get the value in this object?

Tags: php, mysql, object

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MIN(budgetmin)] => 2 [MAX(budgetmax)] => 25 [AVG(budgetmin+budgetmax)] => 30 [VALUE] => staff ) )
```

I also try

```
foreach($array_values as $values) { 
    echo $values->MIN(budgetmin);
    echo $values->MAX(budgetmax);
    echo $values->VALUE;
}
```

I don't get any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it by using:

```
echo $values->{'MIN(budgetmin)'};
```

But I would sugest that you rewrite your SQL select-query to something like:

```
SELECT MIN(budgetmin) AS new_column_name, ...
FROM ...
```

Then you can access data easier using the alternative column name:

```
echo $values->new_column_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

The naming of your class properties is unfortunately not very good.

```
$values->MIN(budgetmin);
```

This line is attempting to call a method of `MIN` with an argument of `budgetmin`. This is not what you want.

```
$values->{"MIN(budgetmin)"};
```

This might work for you.

If that fails can you modify the contents of the object to not include brackets?

Comment: Some trolls seem to feel very fun today... since your answer solves OP's problem I give you my vote.

Comment: it's probably timesplinter who may or may not have posted his answer a few seconds before you.

Comment: Thank your amazing help bro David Barker

Answer (score 1):

Your naming convention is far from ideal. Think about selecting the fields with MySQLs `AS` keyword.

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->{'MIN(budgetMin)'} = 2;
$foo->{'MAX(budgetMax)'} = 25;
$foo->{'AVG(budgetmin+budgetmax)'} = 30;
$foo->{'VALUE'} = 'staff';

$fooArray = array($foo);

foreach($fooArray as $fooElement) {
    echo('MIN(budgetMin): '. $fooElement->{'MIN(budgetMin)'} .'<br />');
    echo('MAX(budgetMax): '. $fooElement->{'MAX(budgetMax)'} .'<br />');
    echo('AVG(budgetmin+budgetmax): '. $fooElement->{'AVG(budgetmin+budgetmax)'} .'<br />');
    echo('VALUE: '. $fooElement->{'VALUE'} .'<br />');
}
```

**Output:**

MIN(budgetMin): 2
MAX(budgetMax): 25
AVG(budgetmin+budgetmax): 30
VALUE: staff

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this code: 
 Change your sql query SELECT MIN(budgetmin) as column_name1, MAX(budgetmax) as column_name2 , AVG(budgetmin+budgetmax) as column_name3, VALUE
 Then
 <?php
 foreach($array_values as $values) { 
    echo $values->column_name1;
    echo $values->column_name2;
    echo $values->column_name3;
    echo $values->VALUE;
}
?>
```